# Surface Mesh from 3D dicom using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mesh, dicom

I would like to create a surface mesh from 3D dicom images using MATLAB's Image Processing Toolbox. These are the steps:

1. Read DICOM images:
   http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/accessing-data-in-dicom-files.html
2. Segment image:
   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4879-mri-brain-segmentation
3. Create surface mesh: ??

My question is, how can I create a surface mesh from the segmented image data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Surface Rendering with Matlab](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/CRNL/tools/surface-rendering-with-matlab) by Chris Rorden:

> MATcro is a simple tool for viewing surface meshes and generating them from voxel images (such as 3D MRI and CT scans).

Rorden is the author of the popular MRI viewers MRIcro(n) and MRIcroGL, and his [website](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/CRNL/tools) contains a lot of possibly useful ressources.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [3D Slicer](https://slicer.org). It is an open source package that can load DICOM images and do volumetric reconstruction, has a lot of segmentation tools implemented, and segmentations you create there can be exported as triangular surface meshes.